# Getting continue behavior (not redownloading files already present) using lftp.

Tags: bash, lftp

So, I have a script which downloads stuff from a seedbox. It works great for new files which are in the remote server and then mirrored on my local server. The problem is that when I want, for example, to remove unnecessary files, running the script again re-downloads the same file(s) again. I tried going into the man pages of mirror but it wasn't helpful. Here is the script which mirrors the files:

```
#!/bin/bash

login=XXXX
pass=XXXXXX
host=XXXXX
remote_dir=/files/
local_dir=/home/XXX/XXX

trap "rm -f /tmp/seedroots.lock" SIGINT SIGTERM

if [ -e /tmp/seedroots.lock ]; then
   echo "Synctorrent is running already."
   exit 1
else
   touch /tmp/seedroots.lock
   lftp -p 21 -u $login,$pass $host << EOF
   set ftp:ssl-allow no
   set mirror:use-pget-n 5
   mirror -c -P5 --log=synctorrents.log $remote_dir $local_dir

   EOF

   rm -f /tmp/seedroots.lock
   exit 0
fi
```

Is there an option for mirror which I am missing that doesn't re-download the locally deleted file(s) again?

Comment: Do you want the script to download files from the remote server but ignore files you have deleted locally?  If so I imagine that will be difficult to achieve.  Unless you can rely on the modification time the script will be unable to tell the difference between files you have removed locally and files that were never downloaded.  To achieve that you will probably need to build a local list of "seen" files and ignore those.

Comment: This is more a question about lftp than bash _or_ ftp in general, and should probably be tagged as such (and so described in the summary).

Answer (score 3):

The `mirror` command in lftp has a `--continue` flag which will result in the behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a try to my version of your script (not tested) :

```
#!/bin/bash

login=XXXX
pass=XXXXXX
host=XXXXX
remote_dir=/files/
local_dir=/home/XXX/XXX
files=$local_dir/*

trap "rmdir /tmp/seedroots.lock" 0 1 2 3 15

if [[ -d /tmp/seedroots.lock ]]; then
    echo "Synctorrent is running already."
    exit 1
else
    mkdir /tmp/seedroots.lock

    lftp -p 21 -u $login,$pass $host << EOF
    set ftp:ssl-allow no
    set mirror:use-pget-n 5
    mget $files

    EOF

fi
```

What it does :

- I build a local list of files, and, subsequently, mget all these files on the ftp server with the variable `$files`.
- I replaced the lock file with a dir : search web about **atomicity**. 
  Files are not atomic whereas directories are.
- The trap runs on normal exit and other signals
- If you are using bash, `[[ ]]` tests are more powerfull.
- Indentation is not just an option ;)

Comment: Since you're storing files as a non-array variable, wouldn't this approach fail with filenames containing spaces? Also, you're calculating the _local_ list, but then getting them rather than putting them... wouldn't you need the _remote_ list to get?

Answer (score -1):

If you are just leeching files (not seeding), you can use lftp mirror with `--Remove-source-files` option to remove files at source after transfer (so no duplicate, re-downloads).